# Closing the dialog on Launch submitting the form values and landing to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
<md-dialog-content class="accent-color">
    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row" [hidden]="ftUser" fxLayoutAlign="center">
        <form [formGroup]="custAppDetail" (ngSubmit)="submitDialogData()">
            <div class="flex-item mt20" [hidden]="ftUser">
                <div class="relative flex-row mb20" [hidden]="ftUser">
                    <label>ChooseRef</label>

                    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row">
                        <div class="form-group flex-item mt20" fxFlex="35%">
                            <label>Architecture</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-row">
                            <div class="flex-item mt20" style="width:185px">
                                <div class="project-input mb20">
                                    <md-select placeholder="Choose/Create" class="flex-row" formControlName="archFileSource">
                                        <md-option *ngFor="let env of enviroment" [value]="env.value">{{ env.viewValue }}</md-option>
                                    </md-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-btn-dialog" [hidden]="ftUser">
                        <button md-raised-button class="form-group auto-btn-prime" [disabled]="!custAppDetail.valid" type="submit">LAUNCH</button>

                        <button md-raised-button class="auto-btn-prime" style="background: grey; color: white" md-dialog-close="cancel" type="button">CANCEL</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

Q1. What is the utility of md-dialog-action ,because after placing the buttons under md-dialog-content the buttons are working

Q2.To pass my form data from dialog to parent component I can use dialogRef or eventemitter which would be the right thing to do
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution I have found out using MdDialogRef.close() I can close my dialog when submitting the form whereas for Cancel I can simply use md-dialog-close, might be helpful for somebody looking for an answer.